# why can a char pointer be a char array in C

Tags: c

In C, you can declare an char array either by

```
char []array;
```

or

```
char *array;
```

The later one is a pointer, why can it be an array?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: if you have initial assignments, they are allocated in different position. in the syntax's point of view, * and [] are roughly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers and arrays are two completely different animals; a pointer cannot be an array and an array cannot be a pointer.

The confusion comes from two concepts that aren't explained very well in most introductory C texts.

The first is that the array subscript operator `[]` can be applied to both pointer and array expressions.  The expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`; you offset `i` *elements* from the address stored in `a` and dereference the result.

So if you declare a pointer

```
T *p;
```

and assign it to point to some memory, like so

```
p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );
```

you'll get something like the following:

```
        +---+
     p: |   | ---+
        +---+    |
         ...     |
        +---+    |
  p[0]: |   |<---+
        +---+
  p[1]: |   |
        +---+
         ...
        +---+
p[N-1]: |   |
        +---+
```

`p` stores the base address of the array, so `*(p + i)` gives you the value stored in the `i`'th *element* (not byte) following that address.

However, when you declare an array, such as

```
T a[N];
```

what you get in memory is the following:

```
        +---+
  a[0]: |   |
        +---+
  a[1]: |   |
        +---+
         ...
        +---+
a[N-1]: |   |
        +---+
```

Storage has only been set aside for the array elements themselves; there's no separate storage set aside for a variable named `a` to store the base address of the array.  So how can the `*(a+i)` mechanism possibly work?

This brings us to the second concept: except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array ijn a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In other words, when the compiler sees the expression `a` in the code, it will replace that expression with a pointer to the first element of `a`, unless `a` is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`.  So `a` evaluates to the address of the first element of the array, meaning `*(a + i)` will work as expected.

Thus, the subscript operator works exactly the same way for both pointer and array expressions.  However, this does not mean that pointer *objects* are the same thing as array *objects*; they are not, and anyone who claims otherwise is confused.